# PHP Codeigniter dropdown value from database with same value

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, dropdown

I'm developing a drop-down form with values from a database. My question is how can I display values from the database to the `drop-down` without displaying the same values. I have 2 data in my database which consist of the same value `(Paid)` but when I display it on my dropdown it shows 2 "Paid" values instead of one.

Thank you

Here is my Model :

```
public function getLiveEvents(){
    $query = $this->db->get('live_events');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Here is my View :

```
 <label class="control-label" for="name">Ticket type:</label>
            <select name="type" class="form-control input-md">
                <?php
                        foreach ($sort as $sorts) {

                            echo '<option value="' . $sorts->live_type . '">' . $sorts->live_type.'</option>';
                        }
                        ?>

            </select>
```

Comment: So U want to ignore repeated values right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is that you could filter the data on the query :

```
public function getLiveEvents(){
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('live_type');
    $query = $this->db->get('live_events');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: tried your solution but still gave me 2 options with same value

Answer (score 1):

This should work -

```
public function getLiveEvents(){
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('live_type');
    $this->db->group_by('live_type'); 
    $query = $this->db->get('live_events');
    return $query->result();
}
```